# Swift JSON object with name of something/Integer

Tags: json, swift

I'm using TMDB api and fetching tv show seasons, but seasons I get back are not inside array, but as objects with names: `season/1`, `season/2`. I need to be able to parse tv show with any number of seasons

Is there a way I can convert this to array without worring about how many seasons does the show have?

```swift
struct Result: Codable {
    var season1: Season?
    var season2: Season?
    var id: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case season1
        case season2
        case id
    }
}

struct Season: Codable {
    var id: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
    }
}
```

```
{
"id" : 1234,
"season/1": {
  "id": 1234
   },
"season/2": {
  "id": 12345
   }
}
```

EDIT:
Found a solution in dynamic coding keys

```
private struct DynamicCodingKeys: CodingKey {
       
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DynamicCodingKeys.self)

        var tempArray = [TestSeason]()

        for key in container.allKeys {
            if key.stringValue.contains("season/") {
                let decodedObject = try container.decode(TestSeason.self, forKey: DynamicCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
                tempArray.append(decodedObject)
            } else {
                print("does not contain season \(key.stringValue)")
            }
        }
        season = tempArray
    }
```

Comment: You've just changed the JSON which completely alters the question and doesn't fit with either your text or example data structures!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting back a `Dictionary`, which you can access directly without using your `Results` struct.  The dictionary probably provides a more flexible way of accessing the data than an array, but can also easily be converted to an Array.

As you haven't stated how you'd like the output, the below will convert them to an array of tuples, where each tuple is (season, id)

```
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
   let results = try decoder.decode([String:Season].self, from: data)
      .map{($0.key, $0.value.id )}
   print(results) // [("season/2", 12345), ("season/1", 1234)]
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Edit: You also don't need the `CodingKeys` in `Season` as it can be inferred from the properties.  All you need is

```
struct Season: Codable {
   let id: Int
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that inside the result object are many other things and even with this answer I do not know to to parse that

Comment: Hope it helped.  It's rather hard to tell you how to decode "many other things" when they are unknown.  If you can add more detail to the question I could probably expand the answer to include them.